# Debugging the solaris 10 sparc device drivers with gdb

Tags: solaris, device-driver

How can we debug Solaris 10 (Sparc) device drivers like we debug user processes using gdb?

Answer (score 2):

By using the mdb & kmdb debuggers:

- [Solaris 10: Writing Device Drivers: Debugging Tools](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-4854/euxdb/index.html)
- [Modular Debugger (mdb) community](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+mdb/WebHome)

Comment: Can we use mdb -k to debug using the source code? If so how to add the source file location?

Comment: @suresh: Sorry, but no - mdb is not a source code debugger like dbx/gdb.